# Marginal and Joint Distribution

Tags: marginal-distribution

[image]

Find the marginal probability density function of x.

I found the marginal of y but cannot understand how to find the marginal of x.
Can someone explain how do we approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For $x \geq 0$, $f(x,y)$ is defined for $y > x$. Hence
$$f(x) = \int_{y=x}^{\infty}f(x,y) \mathrm{d} x=\int_{t=0}^{\infty} e^{-x}\frac{t e^{-t}}{4}\mathrm{d}t, $$
which can be solved by integration by parts.

For $x \leq 0$, $f(x,y)$ is defined for $y >-x$, which can be solved then similarly.